# VBA to consolidate multiple work books with different columns

Tags: vba, excel

I want to consolidate multiple workbooks into one master workbook using VBA as this will be reused. How can I achieve this.

Here is an example

[image: woorkbook]

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant but the question is very vague ...

```
Sub merge()
    Dim aWkbk As Workbook
    Dim aWkSht As Worksheet
    Dim thisWkbk As Workbook

    Set thisWkbk = Application.Workbooks("Book1")
    For Each aWkbk In Application.Workbooks
        If aWkbk.Name <> "Book1" Then
            For Each aWkSht In aWkbk.Worksheets
                aWkSht.Copy after:=thisWkbk.Worksheets(thisWkbk.Worksheets.Count)
            Next aWkSht
        End If
    Next aWkbk
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks For the quick reply on this one.So I agree that the question is not clear.Hence here is an example-

Comment: I Could have multiple such workbooks as shown in the screen shot above.I need to look for the same category and  subcategory ,find the names and calculate the projected hours for each student.